# Can't reference PCL library within Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to build an Android and iOS app with Xamarin using a shared PCL library. I'm following the tutorial on the Xamarin website [1].

I have created my PCL solution, which currently doesn't do anything, and I'm now trying to reference it from another Android solution.

The documentation indicates I should use `References` and then select `Projects`. However, when I do this, I can't either see or find a way to add my PCL library project as a reference.

How can I add my PCL library solution as a reference in another solution?

[1] http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/#Using_PCL

Comment: Are both projects in the same solution?

Comment: Hi. No. These are two different solutions. I mean, I would assume if they were in the same solution I wouldn't have to reference anything, right?

Comment: Small addition that is somewhat related; It turns out that you can't add Unit Tests to a PCL project/solution (??) and you have to create a "separate" project for this. When I do this, i.e. create a cross platform NUnit project, I'm also not able to reference the PCL project either. I'm at a loss...

Comment: When two solutions are in the same project you can reference the projects and the IDE will automatically build any dependencies for you.  The IDE can't do this automatically - you might have 10 projects in a solution, and the IDE can't determine how the chain of references should work.  If you are referencing projects not in the solution, you have to point the reference directly at the dll generated by the project.

Comment: OK. I think I figured it out. You create your two solutions anywhere you'd like. Then you open your referencing solution (e.g. Android). Then on the Project drop down there is an "Add" menu which allows you the"add" a project to the current solution, this is where you select your PCL project. Now, in the References of your Android project you can finally select your PCL project as a reference. Pheew. It all seems unnecessary complicated and the documentation doesn't really seem mention this.. Thanks for your help..

Comment: Note above I should have said "two projects are in the same solution" - I expanded on this a bit in my answer below.  You don't have to create a new solution for every project - you can add a new (or existing) project to a solution directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is just a container for one or more projects.  One project can be included in multiple solutions.  By including multiple projects in one solution you can reference them from one another, which will allow them to automatically build/update their dependencies when needed.  You can add a new project to an existing solution by doing "Add New Project" in the solution explorer - you don't have to create a complete new solution for each project.